# SQL Server Management Studio v.18 startup time

Tags: ssms, ssms-18

My Studio already have at startup option "Open empty environment".
But stil take some by my opinion long time to startup program.

Any idea why is so slow?

While code sense help is not ready after start, can be seen by starting writing first query.

Comment: How long does it take? Have you measured it?

Comment: Arround 20 seconds. I have 32 GB of RAM and Ryzen 7 CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am very late to reply, but incase someone gets the same delay in startup can fix the problem by following this simple step.

Open Internet Explorer: Options/Advance tab. Then scroll to the bottom of the list and uncheck "Check for publisher's certificate revocation".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio & SSMS / SQL Server Microsoft Studio slow load time *FIX*

Disable Fusion Logging:
Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.
Type regedit and press Enter to open the Windows Registry Editor.
Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion
On the right pane, set the LogFailures DWORD value to 0 to disable logging.
Optionally, also set ForceLog DWORD value to 0 to further ensure logging is disabled.
Close the Registry Editor.
Clean Up Existing Logs (if desired):
Navigate to C:\FusionLog\ in File Explorer.
You can safely delete logs in this directory to reclaim disk space if needed.
Restart SSMS and observe the behavior in Process Monitor again. The flood of Fusion Log writes should no longer be present.

This changed my start time from 3  to 5 minutes to 5 seconds for both applications.